# Wordpress Featured Image with Different Sizes

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

I am trying to do replicate the image below in wordpress. The problem is I dont know how.

I have this code to control the size of the featured image.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 400, 300, true );
add_image_size( 'post-thumbnails', 400, 300, true );
```

the problem with this code is it is only in charge of **ONE** size which is 400x300 only. How about the others? If you look at the image below, I believe you can see minimum of 3 sizes (3 variants)?

My Wordpress code in Index.php file is plain and simple:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array( 'id'  => "FeaturedImage")); ?>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>You're Lost! </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to hear your opinions on this on how would you implement an html/css code structure on this.

[image]

Comment: good question! unfortunately, this one is also my problem. hope someone will help.

Comment: This would be extremely easier in JavaScript, look at plugins that might achieve this effect. I would suggest Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: I suppose one option would be to use `Custom Fields`, so you could have a Custom Field `name` of `post-type`, and then the value would be either 1,2,3,4 for example - (1 column, 2 column post). Then in your loop, you would check for that value, and using an `if` statement, you would say, if `name` = `1` then echo out the correct `the_post_thumbnail` value.

Comment: You need a javascript / css solution for this, the images are resized in the browser.

Comment: And to get that sort of layout, then I would use Isotope, as mentioned above. Or Masonry - http://masonry.desandro.com/ by the same people.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i will try my luck on Isotope.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use add_image_size to add more size ?

```
add_image_size( 'another-thumbnails', 150, 300, true );
add_image_size( 'another2-thumbnails', 300, 150, true );
```

You can also use Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ (js library) to fit your needs, it will arrange blocs to be well displayed.

Another way is to use timthumb (php lib http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php) to generate cropped image on the fly (no need to generate multiple size on each upload file).

In your case there is 2 things :

- use add_image_size or timthumb to generate multiple image size
- use masonry to display blocs well